# testcafe using amazon-congnito-identity-js script fails only on IE or Edge

Tags: automated-tests, amazon-cognito, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

When we run testcafe on IE or Edge, it aborted.(Chrome/Safari/Firefox work fine)
We are using amazon-congnito-identity-js for auth.

the testcafe command

```
testcafe --live edge tests/* --screenshots my-fixture/edge
testcafe --live ie tests/* --screenshots my-fixture/ie
```

this is part of aborting code.

```
await t
        .click('#login')
        .wait(1000);
```

abort message

```
1) - Error in Role initializer -
      An error occurred in the native dialog handler called for a native alert dialog on page
```

so we set a setNativeDialogHandler like this.

```
await t
.setNativeDialogHandler((type, text, url) => {
        throw 'alert was revoked: ' + text;
        })
.click('#login')
.wait(1000);
```

the dialog text is this.

```
NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password.
```

this message may be returned from AWS cognito...

But the username and password are properly set.

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(
      console.log("user is " + username);
      console.log("password is " + password);
      new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
      }), {
        onSuccess: success,
        onFailure: failure,
      })
```

console.log(on debug mode)

```
username is test // <- correct
password is 12345678 // <- correct
```

this error occurs only on IE or Edge.

Can you help me?

**environment**

testcafe: 1.2.1

node: 8.11.3

npm: 5.6.0

IE: 11
Edge: 17,18

---

## Update

Show getting console messages before login, this is the message is displayed.

IE/Edge

```
{"log":[],"info":[],"warn":[],"error":["Error during service worker registration: SecurityError","Error during service worker registration: SecurityError"]}
```

Chrome/Safari/firefox

```
{"log":[],"info":[],"warn":[],"error":[]}
```

```
export const regularAccUser = Role(URL, async (t: TestController) => {
    await t
        .typeText(id, 'test')
        .typeText(pass, '12345678 ');
    
    const message = await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(message));

    await t
        .click('#login')
        .setNativeDialogHandler((type, text, url) => {
            throw 'alert was revoked: ' + text;
            })
        .wait(1000);
    }, { preserveUrl: true }
);
```

React src

```
import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser,
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool(),
  });

console.log("user is " + username);
console.log("password is " + password);

cognitoUser.authenticateUser(
      new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
      }), {
        onSuccess: success,
        onFailure: failure,
      })
```

Comment: This event does not occur on all windows devices, but occurs on some windows devices.devices that do not occur error have high specifications.(like cpu: i9, memory 32GB)

Comment: Could you please provide a small example so that we can reproduce it on my computer?

Comment: @mlosev thank you.we can't provide full of code, because we have NDA.so I'll make sample project.plz give me some time.

Comment: @mlosev sorry for late responsing.and I cannot make sample project... I updated my post. Service worker doesn't work only on IE/Edge, but not other browsers.I'm not sure the problem's cause is this.Do you know why service worker not works on IE/Edge??

Comment: @molsev I've tried running testcafe as localhost. and service worker works on IE/Edge. But the problem didn't resolve. so service worker doesn't matter...

Comment: You can send the full example at support@devexpress.com.